# How to cast variable in .query() function to lower case?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df where I want to query while using values from itertuples() from another dataframe:

```
matching_group = Pandas(Index=0, match='TEST')

df.query("column_a == @matching_group.match")
```

"matching_group" is coming from df.itertuples() and I can't change that data type. The query above works.

But now I need to cast "matching_group.match" to lowercase.

```
matching_group = Pandas(Index=0, match='TEST')

df.query("column_a == @matching_group.match.lower()")
```

This does not work.

It's hard to create a minimal viable example here.

How can I cast a variable used via @ in a df.query() to lowercase?

Comment: are you locked in on using the query function?

Comment: Yes, it must be the .query() for consistency reasons.

Comment: For me working well your solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me working well your code with named tuples, one possible reason for not matching should be trailing whitesapces, then remove them by `strip`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'column_a': ['test', 'tesT', 'No']})

from collections import namedtuple

Pandas = namedtuple('Pandas', 'Index match')
matching_group = Pandas(Index=0, match='TEST')
print (matching_group)
Pandas(Index=0, match='TEST')

df3 = df.query("column_a == @matching_group.match.lower()")
print (df3)
  column_a
0     test
```

---

```
df3 = df.query("column_a.str.strip() == @matching_group.match.lower().strip()")
```

Answer (score 3):

**Input Toy Example**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'test':['abc', 'DEF'],
    'num':[1,2]
})

val='Abc' # variable to be matched
```

**Input df**

```
    test    num
0   abc     1
1   DEF     2
```

**Code**

```
df.query('test == @val.lower()')
```

**Output**

```
    test    num
0   abc     1
```

**Tested on pandas version**
pd.**version** # '1.2.4'